# Timeout on ASP.NET after 30 seconds, on SQL server 2008 R2 no timeout

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a ASP.NET MVC3 project accessing a SQL server 2008 R2 database.
If I run a statement in runtime, I get a timeout after 30 seconds.
When running the same statement in SQL server management studio there is no timeout and I get a result after 3 seconds which is acceptable.
While this is a test environment it seems I am the only person having sleeping processes from open windows in my management studio.
To get access to the SQL server I use
System.Data.SqlClient
and have the connection string stored in the web.config
When a controller wants to access the database I fetch the connection string

`Data Source=192.168.111.111;Initial Catalog=agkamed_dev;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=test;Password=wrongpassword;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;`

and in addition set

`SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SNAPSHOT`

Please ask, if any further information is required.

Question: What is responsible for the long delay on ASP.NET side?

Comment: I guess the execution plan, SQL Server can use different execution plan for managment studio and .net.

Comment: Is that the full error - `Connection to server timed out` or there's something else. Would you copy-paste the exact error in your question?

Comment: Yes, that should the full error. Here is the original German message
"Timeout abgelaufen. Das Zeitlimit wurde vor dem Beenden des Vorgangs überschritten oder der Server reagiert nicht." which means "Timeout ran out. Time limit has been exceeded before finishing the process or the server doesn't answer."

Comment: For me this seems more like internet or permission issues. Check if the `ID` and `Password` values in your web.config are correct. If by any chance you are using server on your local machine for development and and try your application is using another server, make sure you can connect to it. Also, but just for check, in the `Connection string` replace the `Persist Security Info=True` with `Integrated Security=False` (delete the first and try with the second).

Comment: Other statements work fine. So permission issues can be excluded. This is not a local server I want to access. It's in a VPN. I changed the security parameter in the connection and restarted the project without succeed

Comment: Hmm, sorry, no other ideas. Good luck with solving this problem though.

Answer (score 0):

Differences in performance / result of a query executed from C# and SQL Server Management Studio are often attributable to differences in ANSI settings.

Note that SSMS will by default set ANSI_NULLS, ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_NULLS on, which won't be the case for C# (see Tools/Options/Query Execution/SQL Server/ANSI)

I would suggest you experiment with setting these off one by one until you get the same behaviour as your C# code.  Then modify your query so that it isn't dependent on these settings.

Comment: Good idea, but adopting the execution parameters didn't make any difference:
`set nocount on;

set arithabort on;

set noexec off;

set parseonly off;

set statistics time off;

set concat_null_yields_null on;

set statistics io off;

set query_governor_cost_limit 0;

set deadlock_priority NORMAL;

set transaction isolation level read committed;

set quoted_identifier on;

set ansi_null_dflt_on on;

set implicit_transactions off;

set cursor_close_on_commit off;

set ansi_padding on;

set ansi_warnings on;
set ansi_nulls on`